# Angular 2 json prettify print filter .replace error

Tags: javascript, angular

Found this solution to do a pretty print of JSON in the HTML however I'm getting `.replace` error. I'm not seeing any thing wrong with the code unless I'm being blind.

error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'prettyprint'
})
export class PrettyPrintPipe {
   transform(val) {
    return JSON.stringify(val, null, 2)
      .replace(' ', '&nbsp;')
      .replace('\n', '<br/>');
  }
}
```

Hmm that didn't seems to do its job, thought it'd pretty print it but it added `/` instead.

[image]

Comment: Check that the `<br/>` in the `replace()` can be written as `&lt;br&gt;`.. Can you provide an the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You should check value the value before apply `replace` function over it.

**Pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'prettyprint'
})
export class PrettyPrintPipe {
   transform(val) {
    if(typeof(val) == "undefined") return ''; //check value before process it.
    return JSON.stringify(val, null, 2)
      .replace(' ', '&nbsp;')
      .replace('\n', '<br/>');
  }
}
```

Comment: This will prevent every [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value from being stringified. Why should `null` be converted to `''`?

Comment: @Andreas good point, does updated would be great idea.. thanks for heads up :)

Comment: `null` is an absolutely valid input for `JSON.stringify()` -> `JSON.stringify(null) === "null"`

Comment: Yeah looks like the val was null/undefined, thanks for pointing. However I edited the post above with image, as I thought it would pretty print it with this pipe filter.

Answer (score 0):

Check that [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string..

Note that you can improve the [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to replace all occurrences in the given JSON to get the expected result:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'prettyprint'
})
export class PrettyPrintPipe {
    transform(val) {
        let result = '';
        try { 
            result = JSON.stringify(val, null, 2)
                .replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')
                .replace(/\\n/g, '&lt;br&gt;');
        } 
        catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
        finally { 
            return result; 
        }
    }
}
```

Example using `transform()` function:

```js
var json = {"id":1,"name":"A green door foo \n bar","price":12.50,"tags":["home","green"]},
    transform = function (val) {
      let result = '';
      try { 
        result = JSON.stringify(val, null, 2)
        .replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')
        .replace(/\\n/g, '&lt;br&gt;');
      } 
      catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      finally { 
        return result; 
      }
    };

// Result empy and logs the error in console
console.log(transform(undefined));

// Transform the provided "val"
console.log(transform('some string with a\nnew line...')); 
console.log(transform(json));
console.log(transform({}));
console.log(transform(true));
console.log(transform(false));
console.log(transform([1, 'false', false]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: And this should fix the `TypeError`? O.o

Comment: In your code you are replacing only the first occurrence.. Even if you provide a JSON

Comment: The question is about the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`, and this is not my question ;)

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Tried yours on plnkr seems to work fine, however if you look at the image on my question I keep getting that kind of structure when its printed. Separated the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289237/angular-2-prettify-json-pipe-filter

Comment: @nCore i have updated the response to handle the error if any.. Can you provide the JSON?