# Angular 2 prettify JSON pipe filter

Tags: javascript, angular

Strange I'm trying to print my JSON in pretty formatted way however my JSON keeps returning with `\` and not being printed pretty.

I have this solution which works on plnkr but not on my actual application. The image below is the printed JSON which is similar to what I have on plnkr.

Can anyone shed a light why this is happening?

Plnkr sample:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqOXS30XPTu9ponWFdgZ?p=preview

Code pipe:

```
    @Pipe({
  name: 'prettyprint'
})
export class PrettyPrintPipe {
   transform(val) {
    if(typeof(val) == "undefined" || typeof(val) == null) return ''; //check value before process it.
    return JSON.stringify(val, null, 2)
      .replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')
      .replace(/\\n/g, '&lt;br&gt;');
  }
}
```

JS Object, I need to `JSON.stingify` the two objects so I can `concat` or add the `childObj` inside the parent.

[image]

```
var parentJSONObj = JSON.stringify(object)
var childObj = JSON.stringify(object) // in a diferent schema 
this.output = parentJSONObj.replace(replaceObj, childObj) // and need to replace a property inside childObj
```

so `this.output` is the final JSON structure which ***I think*** is already a JSON string, adding the pipe filter gives adds slashes. When I try `JSON.parse(this.output)` it gives me an error of `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 214`

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Angular 2 has a built-in pipe for formatting JSON data. Just change your HTML template to this:

```
<pre>{{ x | json }}</pre>
```

Your custom pipe is simply replicating a native feature.

Below is the full source of the JSON pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'json', pure: false})
export class JsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string { return JSON.stringify(value, null, 2); }
}
```

See: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/json_pipe.ts

Comment: Yeah I've seen that one however every time I put a pipe filter `json` its always adding a `\` in the structure.

Comment: its adding slashes I think its because its `JSON.stringify` which is already a stringed JSON, that's what the filter is doing.

Comment: Well yes, if you stringify a JSON string then you'll get the slashes.

You could call `JSON.parse()` on the string and then pass it through the JSON pipe.

Comment: See the edit in my question, I tried `JSON.parse` the `this.output` but it keeps giving me error of `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 214` unless its already an `object`, so if so then the JSON pipe shouldn't add slashes because it converts back to `String`?

Comment: just replace \ with emoty string

Comment: @DanWilson any way to add line number before each line too?

Comment: Not without writing a custom filter.

Answer (score 4):

Change **`div`** tag to **`pre`** tag,

```
<pre [innerHTML]="x | prettyprint"></pre>
```

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/bpisrwlf2aFZFteapwY1?p=preview**

Comment: Still the same, I updated the plnkr and printing the JSON like `<div> {{ x | prettyprint }} </div>` and now it added lots of stuff. Though, I'm planning to put this JSON in a textarea so its editable therefore if I put it in `pre` tag then user can't edit it. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqOXS30XPTu9ponWFdgZ?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pn3SqPEElT7dgtjg4LL6?p=previewn with `textarea` and `pre` tag

Comment: Infact without pretag it is also working !  https://plnkr.co/edit/cLOy1BWjS4NDGGBiMBvs?p=preview

Comment: Yeah looks like it but my actual JSON output is still adds `\` so strange.

Comment: Looks like its when I convert the `object` to `JSON.stringify` it adds the slashes, is there any work around this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS solution:

```
code {
   white-space: pre; 
}
```

I created a working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wULnv7b3tsKrML6hslWu?p=preview

Comment: Still the same, I updated the plnkr and printing the JSON like `<div> {{ x | prettyprint }} </div>` and now it added lots of stuff. https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqOXS30XPTu9ponWFdgZ?p=preview

Comment: Why you need the replace functions?

Comment: Well idea is to put he JSON in a textarea but if its in a `pre` tag then its not editable at all. I thought doing a pipe filter would print it pretty.

Comment: You should said this in the first place.

Comment: Yeah sorry, was just trying to work out the filter first but that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason in my actually code its still adding that `\` when I put a pipe filter even just the regular ` x | json `.

Answer (score 0):

2021 update: I built my own custom version of pipe which not only prettifies but also add colors to json like vscode. Documented how to create that pipe here on the [blog post](https://pranavsarda.hashnode.dev/prettyjson)

Source code of the pipe available on my [Github repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y79Yb.jpg)

Sample output:

[image: see output]

You can try out this at

[Run prettyjson](https://sardapv.github.io/json-prettier)

Hope this helps