# Angular interpolation problem (Attribute typed by class)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a attribute in the class bellow that is typed by another class (Endereco)

```
import { Endereco } from './endereco';

export class ClienteGet {
    id_cliente: number;
    cartaoCredito: number;
    contato: string;
    status: string;
    enderecos: Endereco[];
    nome: string;
    dataNasc: Date;
}
```

Endereco class

```
export class Endereco {
    id_endereco: number;
    logradouro: string;
    bairro: string;
    uf: string
}
```

When i use interpolation, return [object Object]

```
<td>{{clienteGet.enderecos}}</td>
```

Using clienteGet.enderecos.bairro or another attribute that the class Endereco has, return null

How can i show this class in HTML template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 prettify JSON pipe filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289237/angular-2-prettify-json-pipe-filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're setting the enderecos property to an array of Endereco objects.

```
export class ClienteGet {
    //
    enderecos: Endereco[];
    //
}
```

In your html you'll need to access enderecos like you would an array, i.e.

```
<td>{{ clienteGet.enderecos[0].bairro }}</td>
```